# Want to read an excel file which is already open in MS-Excel

Tags: c#, excel-2010

I need to read an excel file using C#.

The file is already open in MS-Excel and its data is updated at every second through another software.

I need to read the updated data at each second.

Please tell me if any more information is required.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: My question is "How to read such a file which open in excel but not saved on the disk ?"

Comment: Where's the file saved ?

Comment: @lstern  The file is not saved. There is a software which displays its data in an excel file and updates it periodically (maybe through a macro). I cannot get the data from the software, so I want to get it from the excel which is opened.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still trying to understand your question. There's and excel file somewhere ? (where?) How do you open the excel file ? Do you click in a link ?

Comment: I think it is not possible a file that not saved to open with a software!

Comment: @lstern ok let me try to explain... suppose I open Ms-Excel and type something into cell A1. I haven't saved the file yet. Now I want to read the contents of the cell A1 through C#.

Comment: bhai tamo ne aa saval no javab mali gayo hoi to ahiya Amo sathe bhag padavo nahitar amaari lagni chhin bhinn thai jase.........;)

Comment: @BhavinChhatrola tamo ne amo ni mantarvama anero anand ave che?

Comment: Bhai amo tamo ni mantrata nathi , amo tamo ne amari smruti ma vagodi chhi jem tamo to amone kadi tamoni smruti ma vagodata nathi .... raheva do tamo ne nai samjay.....ke aaama kevo aalhadak aanand aave ..........

Comment: @BhavinChhatrola Tamo ee amo ne tamari smruti ma vagodela... enathi vadhare amo ee tamo ne amari smruti ma va-go-de-la.... tamo to lagna na bandhan ma bandhaya baad ema etla vyast thai gayela ke amo ne to sav bhuli j gayela....

Comment: Amo pn Bhagwan ne ev ij prathna kariye chhiye ke tamo jaldi thi lagna na bandhan ma bandhai jav ne vyast raho amo ni jem tamo ni ardhagni sangathe...ane..tamo pn amone amari jem j smruti ma vagodo...:)

Answer (score 0):

You can to use the [Visual Studio for the Microsoft Office System (VSTO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc580619.aspx) if you have Visual Studio 2010 or better or (as Vandenbussche said) you can use the Office Interop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Microsoft.Office.Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.11%29.aspx) to open an excel instance and use the object you created to send or receive information from the instance opened that way.

Here are some tutorials that might help:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel

http://dontbreakthebuild.com/2011/01/30/excel-and-c-interop-with-net-4-how-to-read-data-from-excel/

Comment: These are examples where the excel file is actually saved on the hard drive. In my case, the file is not saved on the hard drive, but its just a new excel workbook in which data is dynamically updated every second... I need to read that data on each second.